# Keyboard shortcut does not trigger action anymore after some simple steps

Tags: delphi, action, shortcut

I have a form with a richedit and an edit.
I define an action with a keyboard shortcut Ctrl B that should trigger it.

I only want the action to be triggered in the richedit, in the edit I want the default processing. So I decide to assign and deassign the action handler, respectively in the richedit onEnter and onExit handlers.

When I first press Ctrl B in the richedit, the action fires, fine.
Then I switch to the edit and press Ctrl B, I get a beep, fine.
When I switch back to the richedit and press Ctrl B, the action does not fire anymore, ouch.

I have debugged the VCL code but have not been able to understand if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong (Delphi 2007 and Delphi 10.2).

```
unit Unit5;

interface uses ActnList,Classes,ComCtrls,Controls,Forms,StdCtrls,Windows;

type TForm5 = class(TForm)

    RichEdit1   : TRichEdit;
    Edit1       : TEdit;

    ActionList1 : TActionList;
    Action1     : TAction;

    procedure Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);

    procedure RichEdit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure RichEdit1Exit(Sender: TObject);

 end;

var Form5: TForm5;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm5.Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  richedit1.selText := '{Ctrl B}';
end;

procedure TForm5.RichEdit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  action1.OnExecute := Action1Execute;
end;

procedure TForm5.RichEdit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  action1.OnExecute := NIL;
end;

end.
```

I know that as I want the action to be executed only in the richedit, an easy workaround consists in using the OnKeyDown handler of the Richedit instead of an action.

But I would like to understand why the current code fails. Delphi bug, or misuse of the action "model"?

Comment: Why not toggle the `Enabled` property instead of reassigning the handler?

Comment: As mentioned, there is no difficulty in finding a workaround, I am looking for an explanation to the fragility of the current delphi actions implementation which breaks with this example. By the way if I toggle Enabled and my edit control has an onKeyDown handler that takes care of Ctrl B, pressing Ctrl B in the edit control will be processed in the onKeyDown handler, but I will get an additional beep which is unwanted. My workaround would be not to use an action at all if I want the action only in one control, but handle it in the OnKeyDown handler.